# Resurrecting coefficients from simulated data in Poisson regression

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, poisson, coefficients, exp

I am trying to understand how to resurrect model estimates from simulated data in a poisson regressions. There are other similar posts on interpreting coefficients on StackExchange/CrossValidated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/how-to-interpret-coefficients-in-a-poisson-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128926/how-to-interpret-parameter-estimates-in-poisson-glm-results), but I think my question is different (although admittedly related). I am trying to resurrect known relationships in order to understand what is happening with the model. I am posting here instead of CrossValidated because I am thinking that it is less of statistical interpretation and more of how I would get a known / simulated relationship back via code.

Here are some simulated data `y` and `x` with known relationships to some response `resp`

```
set.seed(707)
x<-rnorm(10000,mean=5,sd=1)
y<-rnorm(10000,mean=5,sd=1)        
resp<-(0.5*x+0.7*y-0.1*x*y) # where I define some relationships
```

With a linear regression, it is very straight forward:

```
summary(lm(resp~y+x+y:x))
```

The output shows the exact linear relationship between x, y, and the interaction.

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.592e-14  1.927e-15  8.260e+00   <2e-16 ***
y            7.000e-01  3.795e-16  1.845e+15   <2e-16 ***
x            5.000e-01  3.800e-16  1.316e+15   <2e-16 ***
y:x         -1.000e-01  7.489e-17 -1.335e+15   <2e-16 ***
```

Now, if I am interested in a poisson regression, I need integers, I just round, but keep the relationship between predictors and response:

```
resp<-round((0.5*x+0.7*y-0.1*x*y),0)
glm1<-glm(resp~y+x+y:x,family=poisson())
summary(glm1)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.419925   0.138906   3.023   0.0025 ** 
y            0.163919   0.026646   6.152 7.66e-10 ***
x            0.056689   0.027375   2.071   0.0384 *  
y:x         -0.011020   0.005261  -2.095   0.0362 *
```

It is my understanding that one needs to exponentiate the results to understand them, because of the link function. But here, neither the exponentiated estimate nor intercept + estimate get me back to the original values.

```
> exp(0.419925+0.163919)
[1] 1.792917
> exp(0.163919)
[1] 1.178119
```

How do I interpret these values as related to the original `0.7*y` relationship?

Now if I put that same linear equation into the exponential function, I get the values directly - no need to use `exp()`:

```
resp<-round(exp(0.5*x+0.7*y-0.1*x*y),0)
summary(glm(resp~y+x+y:x,family=poisson()))
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.002970   0.045422   0.065    0.948    
y            0.699539   0.008542  81.894   <2e-16 ***
x            0.499476   0.008912  56.047   <2e-16 ***
y:x         -0.099922   0.001690 -59.121   <2e-16 ***
```

Can someone explain to me what I am misinterpreting here, and how I might find the original values of a known relationship without first using the `exp()` function, as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're neglecting the fact that the Poisson GLM uses a log link (exponential inverse-link) by default (or rather, you're not using that information consistently). You should either generate your 'data' with an exponential inverse-link:

```
resp <- round(exp(0.5*x+0.7*y-0.1*x*y))
```

or fit the model with an identity link (`family=poisson(link="identity")`).  (I wouldn't recommend the latter, as it is rarely a sensible model.)

For what it's worth, it's harder to simulate Poisson data that will *exactly* match a specified set of parameters, because (unlike the Gaussian where you can reduce the variance to arbitrarily small values) you can't generate real Poisson data with arbitrarily little noise. (Your `round()` statement produces integers, but not Poisson-distributed outcomes.)

Comment: I think that makes sense. Is it safe to say that it is non-sensible to think about those coefficients not on the log scale? Or in other words, does it not make sense to generate data without the exponential inverse-link because the log link will make the relationship non-linear?

Comment: Yes, unless (1) you're going to use an identity-link Poisson or (2) you're intentionally trying to understand the effects of model misspecification (i.e., fitting a model that assumes exponential relationships to data that are generated with a linear relationship).